# Expert’s opinion required to sharing code between two Next.js projects

Tags: next.js, reusability

Currently we have our main domain www.example.com developed using Angular 4 where we have huge Performance and SEO issues.  Using Next.js we have developed m.example.com targeting mobile users and we have successfully gone live recently. Now we want to migrate our main domain www.example.com to Next.js where currently 100% code will be same with respect to consumption of APIs. Only design will be changed to adapt to desktop users. In future we may introduce mobile / desktop specific features, so once we are done with the migration, we wanted to have two independent deployable projects.

Could you please let me know what is the best way of solving this and at the same time achieving the following?
1.  Code reusability between two Next.js projects
2.  Common components between two Next.js projects

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing special related to Next.js you can still share just React components.
I would recommend to put everything into a [monorepo](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/doc/design/monorepo.md). Create a npm package which contains all your components and consume them in your Next.js projects.

You will end up in a project structure like this:

```
packages/myapp-legacy
packages/myapp-mobile
packages/myapp-desktop
packages/ui-components
package.json
```

With tools like [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) you can manage multiple packages in your monorepo. The best approach is to use `yarn` with lerna because lerna [supports](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/blob/master/commands/bootstrap/README.md#--use-workspaces) yarn workspace feature.